# ionic 4 change toolbar background color Dynamically from api get

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to update the toolbar background color via color I am getting from API. I can call the color into app perfectly fine.

`{
  acf: {
  tob_bar_color: "#dd003b"
  }
}`

I am trying to get background color like this:

```
<ion-toolbar [ngStyle]="{'background':styles?.acf.tob_bar_color}">
```

When I inspect element, it shows it adds a `style="background: #dd003b;"` but it still wont change background color. In the inspector if I add '--' in front of background like this: `style="--background: #dd003b;"` it does update the app, but that is only in inspector. But

Comment: so did you try doing style binding to —background?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I havent yet, I am still pretty new to angular. Can you give me an example? In my research, nothing showed that as an option.

Comment: I meant this: <ion-toolbar [ngStyle]="{'--background':styles?.acf.tob_bar_color}">

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes, I tried that and nothing even shows in the inspector. Now this shows up ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]", but I did this in content block to make sure I am getting the color. {{ styles?.acf.tob_bar_color }} and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should add your customer colors this way:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors#adding-colors

Specifically use this color generator from that article: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors#new-color-creator

Now go into your app's folder theme\variable.scss and add new colors. Below I added 4 colors and named them color_a, color_b, color_c, color_d. You can add as many as you like:

variables.scss:

```
:root {
  /** primary **/
  --ion-color-primary: #488aff;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 72,138,255;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #fff;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #3f79e0;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #5a96ff;

  /** custom **/
  --ion-color-color_a: #111111;
  --ion-color-color_a-rgb: 17,17,17;
  --ion-color-color_a-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-color_a-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-color_a-shade: #0f0f0f;
  --ion-color-color_a-tint: #292929;

  --ion-color-color_b: #333333;
  --ion-color-color_b-rgb: 51,51,51;
  --ion-color-color_b-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-color_b-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-color_b-shade: #2d2d2d;
  --ion-color-color_b-tint: #474747;

  --ion-color-color_c: #555555;
  --ion-color-color_c-rgb: 85,85,85;
  --ion-color-color_c-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-color_c-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-color_c-shade: #4b4b4b;
  --ion-color-color_c-tint: #666666;

  --ion-color-color_d: #777777;
  --ion-color-color_d-rgb: 119,119,119;
  --ion-color-color_d-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-color_d-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-color_d-shade: #696969;
  --ion-color-color_d-tint: #858585;

}

.ion-color-color_a {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-color_a);
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_a-rgb);
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-color_a-contrast);
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_a-contrast-rgb);
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-color_a-shade);
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-color_a-tint);
}

.ion-color-color_b {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-color_b);
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_b-rgb);
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-color_b-contrast);
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_b-contrast-rgb);
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-color_b-shade);
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-color_b-tint);
}

.ion-color-color_c {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-color_c);
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_c-rgb);
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-color_c-contrast);
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_c-contrast-rgb);
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-color_c-shade);
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-color_c-tint);
}

.ion-color-color_d {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-color_d);
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_d-rgb);
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-color_d-contrast);
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-color_d-contrast-rgb);
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-color_d-shade);
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-color_d-tint);
}
```

Once your colors are part of the app's css you could do something like this in your html template:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar [color]="dynamicColor? dynamicColor:'primary'">
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 4 template
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-button (click)="updateColor('color_a')" color="color_a">Update Color with color A</ion-button>

  <ion-button (click)="updateColor('color_b')" color="color_b">Update Color with color B</ion-button>

  <ion-button (click)="updateColor('color_c')" color="color_c">Update Color with color C</ion-button>  

  <ion-button (click)="updateColor('color_d')" color="color_d">Update Color with color D</ion-button> 

</ion-content>
```

Then in your ts file you can have initially undefined color var, which then gets its value dynamically from an API or via button:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.css'],
})
export class HomePage {

  dynamicColor: string;

  updateColor(color) {
    this.dynamicColor = color;
  }

}
```

Here is the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-idsm2c

So if your API returns dynamically a color value (#323242) you can have a color map in your ts file that would map it into specific scss color (color_a etc) and thus you can make this dynamic color update for ion-toolbar or buttons etc

Comment: So I have to pass only property name via API, I can't pass a hex color such as "#dd003b"

Comment: So API only returns something like "top_bar_color"? even so I think you can name that way your custom colors in themes scss file.

Comment: Here is the demo URL for API: https://www.churchapp.pro/demo/wp-json/acf/v2/options/

Comment: so the API can return any arbitrary color? "bottom_bar_color":"#1e73be" - like here the #color part can be anything right? so you need it to support dynamic colors and thats why you can't use what I proposed?

Comment: That is correct. I need to have it dynamic. So the way you proposed won't work for what I need.

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @AnthonyI double checked and I do not think what you want to achieve is doable with ion-toolbar specifically. The reason for that is cause scss vars can't be altered at run-time (css can) and there is no proper way to alter ion-toolbar style since its using "shadow dom" so options are either use the approach I mentioned (and just preset as much colors as possible in theme.scss) or do some "hacking" potentially creating a directive that would inject style and alter ion-toolbar style. Another way - instead of toolbar use another custom element.

Comment: I will post a "hack" though;)

Comment: how about this. Maybe I have several theme file import, and use the direct theme as it selected. So if client chooses "style1.scss" it uses the style1.scss, ect. or style2.scss. That way I can just update all styles in that specific style only for style1.scss or style2 or whatever the custom style I choose to have as an option. Do you feel that would be better?

Comment: Yeah I think you can do that. How many styles / classes you think you will have available for users? 10? 100?

Comment: Is there a better way to communicate? And I think for now I will have just a few, but possibly move into over 10. I think if I do more then that, I would want to do a complete custom option so that there isnt a heavy load importing all the scss when only one of them is used for that app only and based on what the user selects for the API. @Sergey Rudenko

Comment: ill add some implementation detail for how i would do it if API only returns 10-20 color codes.

Comment: @AnthonyI updated the answer with what I think I would do in my app. I only did dynamic implementation via buttons, but I think you should now know how to do that  with API