# Can I change ion-item custom css property --background dynamically in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

How do we set dynamic background colors? I need to render ion-item elements based on an array. I need to set the background color in the ngFor loop, coming from each value in the array. Any ideas?

I've tried something like this. But it doesnt work

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
     <ion-item [style.--background]="'shift.color'">{{ shift.color }} qwe</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Check this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-how-to-set-css-custom-properties-dynamically/148500

Comment: check this q - I think my answer is applicable here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203981/ionic-4-change-toolbar-background-color-dynamically-from-api-get

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
     <ion-item [style.background]="shift.color"> {{shift.color}} qwe</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: For ion-item in ionic 4 this does not work i need to change custom css variable --background for change background-color

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do this just by changing it like,

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
     <ion-item [color]="shift.color">{{ shift.color }} qwe</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stackblitz for you too, to show how this all works:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-ngstyle-and-ngclass

The above answers will work surely, but let me tell you that there are other ways of doing it and it doesn't matter if you do it in a static manner or dynamic, it would be used in a dynamic way.

```
/* Your way (mistake is that you added -- before the string and you used shift.color with '' so it gets passed as string) */
<ion-list *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
     <ion-item [style.background]="shift.color">{{ shift.color }}qwe</ion-item>
</ion-list>

/* using ngStyle (you can add a fall back color if shift.color doesn't exist) */
<ion-list *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
     <ion-item [ngStyle]="{'background-color': shift?.color ? shift.color : 'red' }">color</ion-item>
</ion-list>

/* another way is to use ngClass where you can define classes for the color codes and from the backend you get class names which I believe are more readable and you can remember */
<ion-list *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
     <ion-item [ngClass]="{'color-green': shift?.color}">color</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: This will not work with Ionic 4 since it uses shadow dom and scss vars can't be changed dynamically.